# Why does my photo have red and green patches on it?

Tags: raw, color, landscape, smartphone, rawtherapee

I am new to photography, so I ran into a problem when trying to edit a photo in Rawtherapee where my picture looks like it has red and green blotches all over it. I took this photo with ProShot on my Pixel 6.

Is there anyway to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Most likely some processing that boosted a color channel more than the others when trying to make things lighter, but hard to tell without seeing your initial picture.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at some dark rock:

[image]

The histogram shows that many pixels have no green or blue components, so they are really a very, very dark red:

[image]

So when you increase their luminosity you increase mostly the red part and their tone shifts towards a more visible red.